# if my form submits the value in database download a pdf which is on server

Tags: php

```
$kite = "INSERT INTO `download` (name,email,contact,program,city,state)

VALUES ('" . $_POST['name'] . "','" . $_POST['email'] . "','" . $_POST['mobile'] . "','" . $_POST['program']."','" . $_POST['city']."','" . $_POST['state']."')";

$query=mysqli_query($sql,$kite);

if($query)
{ ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;/pdf/quadcopter.pdf" download>

 <?php 
}
```

Comment: mention your query clearly with proper code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to download a file, after the form has been submitted:

```
$kite = "INSERT INTO `download` (name,email,contact,program,city,state)
VALUES ('" . $_POST['name'] . "','" . $_POST['email'] . "','" . $_POST['mobile'] . "','" . $_POST['program']."','" . $_POST['city']."','" . $_POST['state']."')";

$query=mysqli_query($sql,$kite);
if($query) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="quadcopter.pdf"');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("/path/to/quadcopter.pdf"));
  readfile("/path/to/quadcopter.pdf");
  die();
} else {
  // query error
}
```

Two observation here:

- you should not use $_POST values directly into your sql statements, as your code is open to sql injection;
- you should not echo any code prior to the header functions inside the code (if you do that, the code will fail).

Comment: the pdf is getting downloaded..but it is unable to load anything..the pdf is on the server

Comment: As far as I can understand you have a pdf file on the server, that you want to download. Can you explain further what do you mean by "it is unable to load anything?"

Comment: By any chance, do you want to start a download AND display something to the user?

Comment: see..something is downloaded..when i open the downloaded file..its says Failed to load PDF document.

Comment: my all pdf is in a pdf folder

Comment: That means that there is a problem with the file on the server. Try to open the downloaded file (not the file on the server, but the file that has been downloaded by the browser) with a text editor, not the pdf application and check if the php script outputted any error there.

Comment: i opened on sublime

Comment: What html code? Like I said before, you should not output anything on your script. Everything that you echo goes into the downloaded file. The line readfile(filename) reads the file from your storage end automatically echo the content. If you echo anything else, then your final file will get corrupted.

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, added a die() line after the readfile() function.

Comment: the code i have written in the query..opens the pdf file ..what should i do

Comment: Like I said, you can not output html code AND download a file from the same php script. If you want to display a confirmation message in the browser (like operation successful) and download a file then you need 2 steps. The first php script makes the query and outputs html code to the user. The outputted html contains javascript that openes a new tab and loads the second php file that outputs the pdf. That way the user sees the html code and is asked to download a file.

Comment: what i want is i have my web page..when a user clicks on a button pop up form is generated where the user will fill in the details..if submit button is entered the values should go to the database..and the pdf should automatically downloaded which is on the server

Comment: If you just want to download, then the code I've put in the answer is all you need. Can you update your question with your entire php script, after you have done the modification I've suggested?

Comment: maybe the header is unable to path the pdf

Comment: If the path to the pdf file is incorrect, then the downloaded file will contain some text that will say that. Are you sure that the downloaded file contains your html code and not a php error, formatted as html. To check that, change the extention of the downloaded file from pdf to html and open it with your browser, then work from the error you see.